# Unable to open the remote project: Environment "master" is inactive

Tags: symfony

I want to use symfonyCloud to deploy a project with those commands :

```
 symfony project:create --title="my_project" --plan=development
 symfony deploy
 symfony open:remote
```

After the last command i get error from the terminal :

```
 Unable to open the remote project: Environment "master" is inactive
```

How could i resolve this?
Thanks for your light

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
symfony deploy
```

only works when no ERROR is reported. If you want to deploy ignoring these errors you have to use

```
symfony deploy --bypass-checks
```

which should bring your project up